# Does $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}Cxy^{\frac{-4}{3}}e^{\frac{-x^3}{9y}} (x>0, y>0)$ converge to delta function?

Tags: distribution-theory

Does $P(x,y) = Cxy^{\frac{-4}{3}}e^{\frac{-x^3}{9y}} (x>0, y>0)$ converge to $\delta(y)$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ for some constant C?

It's easy to check that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}Cxy^{\frac{-4}{3}}e^{\frac{-x^3}{9y}} = 0$.

When it comes to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Cxy^{\frac{-4}{3}}e^{\frac{-x^3}{9y}}dy = 1$ or not, I don't know how to deal with it because it's elementary integral.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: @ Donny The one sided $y$-integral is in fact constant: for $x\gt 0$ we have $\int_0^{\infty } x y^{-4/3} \exp \left(-\frac{x^3}{9 y}\right) \, dy=3^{2/3} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ But a true Delta function would be symmetric in $y$, and this is not the case here.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Your comment is insightful! I think it's exactly what I need! Thanks!

Comment: If the limit exists as a distribution then, since the limit vanishes for all $y \neq 0$, its support is $\{0\}$ and by a theorem the distribution must equal $c_0 \, \delta(y) + c_1 \, \delta'(y) + \cdots + c_n \, \delta^{(n)}(y)$ for some $n$ and some constants $c_0, \ldots, c_n.$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. How can you say that the limit isn't symmetric in $y$?

Comment: @md2perpe, your question hits a point: indeed, the non-even-ness of the "limitands" does not imply that the limit is not even. For that matter, the triangle-tent functions based on $[0,2/n]$ and of height $n$ are asymmetrical about $0$, but certainly do converge to $\delta$.

Comment: @md2perpe Please notice that that for $x>0$ the integral over the negative range of $y$ is not convergent. That's the asymmetry in the problem.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. Yes, but Donny has written "$(x>0, y>0)$" as conditions, so it is given that we shouldn't look at negative $y$. Still, if we extend $P$ by setting $P(x,y)=0$ for $y \leq 0$ then the limit as a distribution is in fact Dirac $\delta(y),$ which is symmetric (even) although the $P(x,y)$ was not.

Comment: @Donny. Please don't forget to mark the answer that you think is best.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands there is a problem. We have functions defined only on $(0,\infty)$ but want to show that they converge as distributions to $\delta$ which has its support outside of this interval. This doesn't fit well with the definition of distributions and limits of such. I therefore take the approach of extending the functions to take the value $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$. In the following I have changed the variables; $x$ is used for the variable of integration ($y$ in the question), and $\epsilon$ for the parameter ($x$ in the question).

First, for $\epsilon>0$, I define $u_\epsilon : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
u_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}
\epsilon \, x^{-4/3} \, e^{-\epsilon^3/(9x)} & (x>0) \\
0 & (x \leq 0).
\end{cases}
$$

Then I take $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and start calculating, using a substitution:
$$\begin{align}
\langle u_\epsilon, \phi \rangle
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \epsilon \, x^{-4/3} \, e^{-\epsilon^3/(9x)} \, \phi(x) \, dx 
= \left\{ \xi := \frac{\epsilon^3}{9x}, \ x = \frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi} \right\} \\
&= \int_{\infty}^{0} \epsilon \, (\frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi})^{-4/3} \, e^{-\xi} \, \phi(\frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi}) \, (-\frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi^2}) \, d\xi \\
&= 9^{1/3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \xi^{-2/3} \, e^{-\xi} \, \phi(\frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi}) \, d\xi \\
&\to 9^{1/3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \xi^{-2/3} \, e^{-\xi} \, \phi(0) \, d\xi \\ 
&\to 9^{1/3} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \xi^{-2/3} \, e^{-\xi} \, d\xi \right) \phi(0) \\ 
&= \langle 9^{1/3} \, \Gamma(1/3) \, \delta, \phi \rangle.
\end{align}$$

Thanks to $\phi(x)$ vanishing for $|x|$ big enough, $\phi(\frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi})$ vanishes for $\xi$ close to $0$. On the other hand, for big $|\xi|$ it might happen that $\phi(\frac{\epsilon^3}{9\xi})$ does not vanish; it actually tends to $\phi(0)$ as $|\xi| \to \infty.$ Luckily, it is bounded, which allows us to take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ inside the integral.

Thus, taking $C = \frac{1}{9^{1/3} \, \Gamma(1/3)},$ we have that $C u_\epsilon \to \delta$ when $\epsilon \to 0+$.

Comment: @ md2perpe Changing variables $x\to \epsilon$, $y\to x$ with respect to the original version you have now just derived the result of my first comment, also you should have noticed that you had to restrict the integration to positive values of $x$. You have now tacitly found the asymmetry I meant in my first comment. Just a final question: how did you come to the rather uncommon expression for the Delta function?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. One difference between my calculation and yours is that you seem not have included a test function in the integral. I thought that it was best to do that, but probably it can be shown that if $u_\epsilon$ gets narrower and has its mass around $x=a$, and $\int u_\epsilon(x) \, dx \to 1$, then $u_\epsilon \to \delta_a$ as distributions.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. I don't think that I restricted the integration to positive values of $x$; that restriction was already given. Instead I extended the function to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by setting it to $0$ for negative $x$. That was necessary since the limit had its support on the boundary of the original domain. Another possibility would have been to let the domain be $[0,\infty)$ and allow the test functions to have a nonzero value at $0$.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. What do you mean is a "rather uncommon expression for the Delta function"?

Comment: Sorry that I'm unfamiliar with notation... What dose $C^{\infty}_{c}(R)$ suppose to mean?

Comment: @Donny. It's the linear space consisting of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support, i.e. they vanish outside of a compact set. Distributions (like $\delta$) are defined as linear functionals on that set.

Comment: @ md2perpe 1) How is your limit defined for negative y? Is it the same as for positive y? 2) See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function for "common" expressions, the most famous is probably the heat kernel.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. Do you know how distributions are defined and how limits in the space of distributions are defined? And why should I use one of the common sequences of functions that converge to Dirac delta when this post is about another, very uncommon, sequence?

Comment: From my understanding, @md2perpe gives a good proof using a “distribution” definition of delta function. Also I don’t see any even property is needed for delta function, so I think it’s reasonable to define P(x,y) = 0 for y < 0.

Comment: @ md2perpe The lengthy discussion shows that my initial comment still comprises the essential statement (including the proof with the calculation of the integral): your function defines a one-sided delta funtion.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. In your comment you say that the integral is constant, but that does not prove that it converges to $\delta$. The integral can be nonconstant and still converge, or it can constant and not converge.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. What is a "one-sided delta funtion(sic!)"?

Comment: A few PDF:s about distribution theory: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf, https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf, https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ramond/docs/cours/distributionsedp.pdf
Note that a couple of these denote the space of compactly supported $C^\infty$ functions with $C_0^\infty$ instead of $C_c^\infty.$

Comment: @ md2perpe Sorry, I really don't understand what you want. Instead of making hypotheses about my knowledge about the topic, why don't you just go the the link in Wikipedia I mentioned 8 comments ago and make yourself familiar with the pargraph "symmetry properties" of the Delta function? You will then probably understand when I consider the discussion finished from my side. Have a good time.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. What I want is to make you understand that my calculation is a proper calculation in the theory of distributions and that it shows that the limit is *the* Dirac delta distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. I ask about your knowledge on the topic since your questions don't make sense for distributions. Finally, my limit is symmetric although the sequence of functions converging are not.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. You are completely right that expressions like $\int_0^1 \delta(y) \, dy$ don't make sense. For ordinary distributions only application ("integrals") on $C_c^\infty$ functions is defined.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. If $f_n$ are even $C^\infty$ functions converging to $\delta$ then $f_n \, H$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function, converge to $\frac12 \delta$; this seems to be what you call a singlesided $\delta$. The limit is however not in any sense singlesided. Only the sequence of functions has a singlesided support.

Comment: @Donny. I added a short prologue to my post.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The answer to the question of the OP is "no".

But it is very easy to extend the definition of your interesting function which then goes to a delta function, and in this manner reconciliate the different positions in the discussion. Just replace $y$ by $|y|$ and you get the full symmetric delta function in the limit:

$$u_{s}(y,\epsilon) = \frac{\epsilon  \left| y\right| ^{-4/3} \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon ^3}{9 \left| y\right| }\right)}{2\ 3^{2/3} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$

It is normalized

$$i_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_{s}(y,\epsilon)\,dx = 1$$

and the integral over the test function $f(x)$ defined in the original post gives

$$i_f = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_{s}(y,\epsilon)f(x)\,dx = \frac{3}{2}$$

This is the same result as that for the integral with the delta function insted of $u_{s}(y,\epsilon)$

*Remark:*

With the same idea but even simpler (and aesthetically pleasing) is this function

$$v(x,\epsilon)=
\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon }{\pi }}\frac{1}{x^2} \exp \left(-\frac{\epsilon }{x^2}\right)$$

**Original post**

My answer to the question "Does $P(x,y) = Cxy^{\frac{-4}{3}}e^{\frac{-x^3}{9y}} (x>0, y>0)$ converge to $\delta(y)$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ for some constant C?" was given in a comment: "The one sided $y$-integral is in fact constant: for $x>0$ we have $\int_0^\infty Cxy^{\frac{-4}{3}}e^{\frac{-x^3}{9y}} \,dy=3^\frac{2}{3} \Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$. But a true Delta function would be symmetric in $y$, and this is not the case here."

So the brief answer is "no".

A lengthy discussion followed up. Here I wish to clarify my point with a simple example, hoping that we can come to a common understanding. Altervatively, I can learn what is wrong with my argument.

I start by defining two functions containing a parameter $w>0$ so that the limit $w \to 0$ each function goes to a delta functions with symmetry properties corresponding to theses functions.

One function is symmetric in $x$

$$s(x,w) = \frac{1}{2w} 
\left\{ 
 \begin{array}{ll} 
  1 & |x| \lt w\\ 
  0 & \text{else} \\ 
 \end{array} 
\right. $$

the other one is unsymmetric

$$u(x,w) = \frac{1}{w} 
\left\{ 
 \begin{array}{ll} 
  1 & 0\lt x \lt w\\ 
  0 & \text{else} \\ 
 \end{array} 
\right. $$

Both functions are normalized

$$n_s = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x,w)\,dx =1$$ 
$$n_u = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,w)\,dx =1$$

Next we define a test function $f(x)$ which intentionally is not continuous at $x=0$ but has a jump

$$f(x) = 
\left\{ 
 \begin{array}{ll} 
  2 & x \gt 0\\ 
  \frac{3}{2} & x =0\\
  1 & x \lt 0 \\ 
 \end{array} 
\right. $$

Now we calculate two integrals

$$i_s = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x,w) f(x)\,dx = \frac{3}{2}$$

$$i_u = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,w) f(x)\,dx = 2$$

Finally we compare the results with that over the standard Dirac delta function in a CAS (here *Mathematica*)  which is

$$i_{\delta} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x)\,dx = \frac{3}{2}$$

We conclude that the symmetric approximation $s(x,w)$ gives the correct result while the unsymmetric does not.

As the function $u_{\epsilon}(y)$ of the OP (considered normalized) is not symmetric the integral over $u_{\epsilon}(y) f(y)$ (is equal to 2 and not the Delta function result $\frac{3}{2}$. Hence I have justified my initial answer.

Comment: In the theory of distributions the test functions should be infinitely differentiable and thus continuous. They should also tend to zero quickly for big $|x|$. Your "test function" satisfies neither of this. Thus you are not working with proper distributions.

Comment: Try to take $f(0) = 3$ instead of $f(0) = \frac32$. In that case you will still get $i_s = \frac32$ and $i_u=2$ but I guess that you will get $i_\delta = 3$ in Mathematica.

Comment: Do you still believe that the limit is not symmetric in $y$ since the sequence is not?